# Sharepoint Excel data table and Chart

Tags: web-part, list, excel, chart

Need help about sharepoint.

I have a table data collection currently in ms excel document look like the following image.

[image]

every last day of the week the information will be updated (append new file) and store to sharepoint document library in the same layout as picture above.

I want to display a single chart on a sharepoint site page that automaticaly linked to the newest uploaded document.

Is it possible ? Any idea/suggestion ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since my question moved here and i think this is the right place to ask, So can someone give me an idea/suggestion about this ? really need it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some .Net experience, you could write an event handler that updates said webpart's target whenever a new document is added to the library. There's plenty of documentation out there on writing event receivers, and also modifying webparts programatically.